# For better SQL performance, Do i check values existence or collect valid values out first?

Tags: php, mysql

For a variable can be spammed with false values like the following

```
$input = $_GET['value'];
```

And a query to get `values == $input` like the following ***`(EXECUTE QUERY)`***

```
SELECT tab.title 
FROM table tab 
INNER JOIN values val 
   ON tab.id = val.id 
WHERE value = :input
```

Does leaving the query like that is better and efficient to my performance or do i check if `$input` actually `exists` like the following

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM values WHERE value = :input);
if (rowCount > 0) {. EXECUTE QUERY .}
```

or do i get the all distinct values from the `values` table and check if it is in the `array` or not like the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM values;
$values[] = $row['value'];
if (in_array($input, $values)) {. EXECUTE QUERY .}
```

Comment: Frankly, no, looking up the same value twice is not a good idea. You would need a compelling reason to do that - such as an expensive follow on query which is not the case in your example. Even if that were the case you would perform the initial check within the same batch taking care to consider that the record could come into existence between the two lookups.

Comment: Are you sure you want `RIGHT JOIN` instead of regulat `INNER JOIN`?? at the moment you check for `value = :input` you lose those null result and become `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'll start using `INNER JOIN` now, i doubted about using `RIGHT JOIN` but i thought it is the fittiest for this.

Comment: @AlexK. I see, I've add another possible path i maybe take at the end, Please check if is better or not.

Comment: If you really want use `RIGHT JOIN` include the filter on the `ON`  condition .. `RIGHT JOIN values val 
   ON tab.id = val.id AND value = :input`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So `INNER JOIN` would be the most efficent at this point? Since i just want to stop the query if `input` values doesn't exist, Does using `RIGHT JOIN` in it would be an overkill?

Comment: Not sure, that depend on what you want to do because return different results. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)